# Getting time in ISO 8601 without dash/hyphen

Tags: javascript

Right now the date is coming out as:

```
2020-11-12T19:11:00.000Z
```

Is there any way to get it as 20201112T191100Z? Basically without the hyphens/colons/period.

I'm getting the date by converting the current format of

```
2020-11-12 11:11:00
```

to

```
2020-11-12T19:11:00.000Z
```

using

```
new Date('2020-11-12 11:11:00').toISOString()
```

I was hoping there'd be a simpler way of formatting it as desired without just splicing/deleting it like a normal string.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The ISO 8601 format is fairly well defined. JavaScript is even only using a subset of it. Why *not* just remove everything you don't need from the string? It's not like there is going to be something totally unexpected.

Comment: Use a regular expression: `.replace(/[-:]/g, '')`

Comment: Will you accept (by clicking on accept) my answer?
And up-vote (when you have 15+ reputation points)?

Answer (score 3):

You could `split` and `join`, `slice` and `concat`:

```
ISODateNoDashesNoColonsNoDecimalNoMilliseconds = 
new Date('2020-11-12 11:11:00').toISOString()
  .split("-").join("")
  .split(":").join("")
  .slice(0,15).concat("Z");
```

Or `replace` using RegExp:

```
ISODateNoDashesNoColonsNoDecimalNoMilliseconds = 
new Date('2020-11-12 11:11:00').toISOString()
  .replace(/-|:/g, "")
  .replace(/\.\d{3}Z/, "Z");
```

Or `split` and `join`, `slice` and `+`:

```
ISODateNoDashesNoColonsNoDecimalNoMilliseconds = 
new Date('2020-11-12 11:11:00').toISOString()
  .split("-").join("")
  .split(":").join("")
  .slice(0,15)+"Z";
```

Or `replaceAll`, `slice` and `+`:

```
ISODateNoDashesNoColonsNoDecimalNoMilliseconds = 
new Date('2020-11-12 11:11:00').toISOString()
  .replaceAll("-", "")
  .replaceAll(":", "")
  .slice(0,15)
  +"Z";
```